# Navigation bar anchor exceeds ul width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my navigation bar to fit android devices. I am using padding so anchors are bigger and easier to click, but using padding on anchors makes ul and nav width to be useless.

Here is my code

```js
const li = document.querySelector('ul');
const a = document.querySelectorAll('a');
const red = location.href.split('/');
const ab = red[red.length - 1];

const currentPage = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    const page = a[i].href.split('/');
    const pageMain = page[page.length - 1];
    if (pageMain === ab) {
      a[i].classList.add('active');
    }
  }
};
currentPage();
li.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {

  li.classList.toggle('color');
});
li.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {

  li.classList.toggle('color');

});
```

```css
.navi {
  float: right;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.navi ul {
  background-color: #212121;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.navi li a {
  margin: 15;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.navi a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navi">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">START</a></li>
    <li><a href="uslugi.html">USŁUGI</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3.html">PAGE 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="kontakt.html">KONTAKT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Thats how it looks on androids
[Menu on android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Tb1h.png)

and here is how it supposed to look (without red field)[Menu on PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b86S.png)

Comment: Hi Daedalus, welcome to SO! We cannot help you unless you post some [reprex] we can check...

Answer (score 0):

Embed li tag inside the anchor tag and give padding to li, so that the click area gets expanded according to the spacing given to li.

```css
.navi {
  float: right;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.navi ul {
  background-color: #212121;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.navi li{
  margin: 15;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.navi a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navi">
  <ul>
    <a href="index.html"><li>START</li></a>
    <a href="index.html"><li>USŁUGI</li></a>
    <a href="index.html"><li>PAGE 3</li></a>
    <a href="index.html"><li>KONTAKT</li></a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).